# Unableto verify site on Magento Security Scan

Tags: security

I am trying to verify my site on the Magento new security scanner https://account.magento.com/scanner/index/form/ but every time I try to verify I get an error  `Unable to verify this site. Please recheck your verification code and try again!` I am using domain name and HTML Comment. I **cannot** see the code in my source when I put the code on my site which I believe that's why it can't be verified. How can I resolve this issue please. I know this question was asked [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198524/magento-security-scan-not-able-to-verify-site/215520#215520) but I did not find my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Click `Generate Confirmation Code` and Copy that generated code, follow the below steps and paste the code

```
1. Click System > Configuration > General > Design. You can add the code to either your HTML header or footer.
2. To add it to the head, click HTML Head and enter the code in the Miscellaneous Scripts field.
3. When you're finished, click Save Config.
```

If still not coming means something blocking in your .htaccess file or firewall.

Comment: Thanks Jeeva, I followed the step to generate the code and added but still no code in the site source. I don't know where to look at to resolve this.

Comment: any restriction on your site URL? Because I too faced an issue like this if we have htaccess password protection for the site means this issue will come. I removed that protection after that it worked for me.

Comment: If your not able to fix this means please check https://www.magereport.com for checking the patches

Comment: Did you check verify after saving that field in Miscellaneous Scripts in magent? If you click verify means verified status will come after that you can able to start the scan.

Comment: There is no restriction on my site URL  and my .htaccess file is not password protected, the only thing is my Magento panel is not on the admin (https://www.example.com/index.php/admin). Yes  checked verify after saving that field in Miscellaneous Scripts in magento

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  Please see https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Security-Scan-Tool/td-p/92549. This places the meta tag in default_head_blocks.xml. This worked for me. Putting the html tag in the default_head_blocks.xml file did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your .htaccess with the default one.
Then add the code to the site, this time the scanner should accept your site to test.
Get the scan report and then place original .htacess file.